# iOS 12.0 : Is there a way to set MFMailComposeViewController navigation bar title's text to white?

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Currently, I haven't found a way to do this for iOS 12.0. I've tried setting bar tint like so.

```
[mailController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Then, I tried setting the title text attribute with the following code

```
   [mailController.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
 @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor WhiteColor]};
```

I've tried more options that I found on StackOverflow, but none of them worked. I am hoping that someone found a reliable way to change the navigation bar title text color.  It stays black no matter what I do. The bar button's colors change correctly, but not the navigation bar title.

Comment: FYI - This same issue is being discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522308/change-title-color-of-navigation-bar-in-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-ios-12-no

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try either one of these which lets you set the navigation bar color. For example: If the navigation bar is black color, then the text is set to white.

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle: UIBarStyleBlack]`

or

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]`