# Change title color of navigation bar in MFMailComposeViewController in iOS 12 not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

How can I change the title color of `UINavigationBar` in `MFMailComposeViewController` in `iOS 12`?

This is what I am doing:

```
import MessageUI

extension MFMailComposeViewController {
    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        navigationBar.isOpaque = false
        navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
        navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    }
}
```

In iOS 10 works:

[image: ios 10]

In iOS 11 works:

[image: ios 11]

In iOS 12 is not working:

[image: ios 12]

Comment: You are not alone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52451156/ios-12-0-is-there-a-way-to-set-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-navigation-bar-titl

Comment: FYI - Overriding a method in an extension is not supported and it is undefined behavior. Please see the Extensions chapter in the Swift book for a large warning telling you this.

Comment: I'm having the same issue (but in Objective-C). I've tried updating the navigation bar in `init`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, and `viewDidAppear`. I've set the window's `tintColor` and I've tried setting the `titleTextAttributes` on both the nav bar and the `UINavigationBar appearance` proxy. Nothing has changed the title in iOS 12. I've even dumped the view hierarchy and there's no sign of a nav bar. But that's true under iOS 10 as well as iOS 12. Time for a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @rmaddy Are you using large titles? Make sure you have set the `largeTitleTextAttributes`, not just the `titleTextAttributes`.

edit: and same for UIAppearance

Comment: not working. Just a bug. Even large title. Seems they skip the appearance loading

Comment: @rmaddy is ok. I'm overriding a method from extension because the New Message view controller is opening from a `UIActivityViewController` and I'm not instantiating a `MFMailComposeViewController`

Comment: @pableiros It's not really OK. It may work. But it may not work. It's undefined behavior to override a method in an extension. It's best to avoid attempting it.

Comment: @ssrobbi Yeah, I already tried setting the color for the `largeTitleTextAttributes` but nothing changed. I don't think large titles are being used anyway. I did file a bug report. Others need to do the same to let Apple know it's affecting lots of people.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry for my english, what I tried to say is I'm agree with your argument about to not override methods from extensions. I did that way because I didn't find another way to achieve that.

Comment: I have filed a bug with Apple as well. I have been unable to find a nice solution or any reason why it wouldn't be working on my end.

Comment: Anyone wants to post the radar? @GabrielPires maybe?

Comment: has anyone found an acceptable way of doing this? it is still an issue in ios13! I have tried every solution posted and i could think of. also tried setting this in the appdelegate where there rest of my apps navigation bar UI is set, didnt work
        `UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [MFMailComposeViewController.self]).tintColor = .white`

Answer (score 0):

```
/// UINavigationBar
     let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBar.appearance()
     navBarAppearance.barTintColor = .red
     navBarAppearance.tintColor = .white
     navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .red

     navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [
         .foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
         .font: UIFont.systemFontSize
     ]
     navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
         .foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
         .font: UIFont.smallSystemFontSize
     ]

     let barButtonAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
     barButtonAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([.font: UIFont.systemFontSize], for: .normal)

     navBarAppearance.isTranslucent = false


     if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
         let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
         appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    
         appearance.backgroundColor = navBarAppearance.backgroundColor
         appearance.titleTextAttributes = navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes ?? [:]
         appearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes ?? [:]
    
         navBarAppearance.standardAppearance = appearance
         navBarAppearance.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried all the way to change the title color, however it doesn't work

Before presenting the mailcomopser controller

I changed the background color to white

and buttons color to black

Here is the code below:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarPosition.any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.default)
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.black], for: .normal)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.black], for: .highlighted)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.clear], for: .disabled)
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.black], for: .selected)
```

[image]

Comment: But the question is about how to change the title color from MFMailComposeViewController in iOS 12

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work in any case, so we need to modify the background color and button colors

Comment: Why it doesn't work in iOS 14?

Answer (score -6):

In your AppDelegate.swift file  in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions block

TRY THIS:

```
    let navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = .blue //your desired color
    navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = .white //your button etc color 
    navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white] //your Title Text color
```

Answer (score -6):

titleView still works fine. Just create view with label in story board [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtBjW.png), with such font, as U need and set it as title view.

```
if let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("WTitleView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? UIView {
            navigationItem.titleView = view
}
```

[image: like this]