# MFMailComposeViewController title color of navigation bar not changed in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

```
let myAttribute =[NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = myAttribute
```

Title color is not change to white. It display in black.

Comment: Please file a bug report at bugreport.apple.com if you haven't already

Comment: This is being discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522308/change-title-color-of-navigation-bar-in-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-ios-12-no